# How these index.html, index.php, .htacess files works ? Whats the purpose of these files?

Tags: php, web

How all these index.html, index.php, .htacess files works ? whats the purpose of these files?

Comment: You need to be more specific. We aren't psychic. Post the contents of these files.

Comment: you are looking at them as you asked your question if you didn't already know that much. I bet google can tell you a lot about this question too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really broad question so I suggest you look it up. But here is start

1. index.html -- The default page that is going to be returned when someone visits your website
2. index.php -- same as above if .html file is not there
3. .htaccess -- loads custom mods or you can rewrite urls. This by it self is a whole book. So start here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Probably be worth starting with the manual for a more recent version of Apache. 1.3 is really old.

Answer (score 3):

The index.* files are default files served if the URL refers to a directory.

The .htaccess file is an opportunity for the developer to provide server configuration parameters that apply to the directory it is in and all subdirectories.